# ./android command works but not android

Tags: android

My android command wasn't working and people were saying it was because I didn't have a path setup to it, but I checked my ./bash_profile and it was set up. So someone suggested I run the command chmod 777 android and then I could run ./android sdk from the tools folder. I did this and it worked and I could run commands but instead of using the android command, I had to use ./android. How can I fix this so I can use the android commmand instead of ./android

Comment: It would help if you posted the output of the command `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Here's the output: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/android-sdks/platform-tools:/android-sdks/tools:/android-sdks/platform-tools:/android-sdks/tools
`

Answer (score 1):

Please check your PATH variable by `echo $PATH`, My best guess is, that the android tools path is not included. In my case it is

```
$HOME/bin/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

`echo $PATH` should print something like this

```
$HOME/android-sdk-linux/tools:$HOME/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If the android sdk dirs are missing in PATH and you set it in `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
. $HOME/.bash_profile
```

will set the PATH.
Make sure `. $HOME/.bash_profile` is sourced when opening the shell. Configurations differ with every linux distribution here.

Comment: This is what it prints out: 
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/android-sdks/platform-tools:/android-sdks/tools:/android-sdks/platform-tools:/android-sdks/tools`

Comment: And is the android binary located in `/andr‌​oid-sdks/tools`? however, this is a strange path to put files into.

Comment: I'm on a mac, and it automatically put it in that folder when I ran eclipse and installed the necessary plugins

Comment: ok, what is the output of this: `which android; ls -l /andr‌​oid-sdks/tools/android`

Comment: /andr​oid-sdks/tools/android: No such file or directory

Comment: And when you say, `./android` is working, in what directory are you? What prints `pwd`?

Comment: any news? did you find your android binary?

Comment: /Users/thomas/android-sdks/tools

Comment: You might notice, that /Users/thomas/android-sdks/tools is not in PATH. Right?

Comment: `/android-sdks/tools` is not the same as `/Users/thomas/android-sdks/tools`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only just installed the android sdk you'll need to source your bash_profile again with the source or dot commands. Alternatively, just close your shell and reopen it.

```
source ~/.bash_profile

. ~/.bash_profile
```

Alternatively, if that's not it `echo $PATH` in a shell and double check there's an entry to the bin folder of the sdk.